# Dynamically Load Classes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.5

I'm trying to define a class dynamically  and then instantiate it . For this what i'm doing is , i have the class definition as a string and i'm feeding it to the eval function to define it during runtime .

```
f="""class f:
    def pr(self):
        print "asdfg"
    """
>>> eval(f)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    eval(f)
  File "<string>", line 1
     class f:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why im doing this is because there are lots of classes that can be used but rarely are they all needed together. Plus i allow user's to add new classes to the application.

Thanks in advance .

Edit -------------------

This is python 2.5 output

```
data = """class f:
    def pr(self):
        print "asdfg"
    """
>>> exec(data)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#14>", line 1, in <module>
    exec(data)
  File "<string>", line 4

   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

#What i think the problem is "\n"
>>> data
'class f:\n    def pr(self):\n        print "asdfg"\n    '
```

im not sure, but that is where the error is pointing.

the reason for using python 2.5 is that , scapy is a part of the program and it has support for only python 2.5.

Comment: If **users** of your program need to create new classes, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: Are you trying to desing some sort of plug-in system, where `f` would be filled with the content of a Python source file?

Comment: @ixe013 : yup , i think the below given solution will work. i actually forgot about it " exec() ".

Comment: @thecreator232 Hm. Maybe try altering `data` so that the closing triple quotes `"""` appear on the end of the third line (so like `print "asdfg" """`? I don't really know why this is happening, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement), not `eval`. `exec` will execute arbitrary code, while `eval` will only evaluate expressions (e.g. `eval('2+3') == 5`).

```
>>> data = """class f:
    def pr(self):
        print "asdfg" """
>>> exec data
>>> instance = f()
>>> instance.pr()
asdfg
```

There is probably a better way to achieve what you want to do, though. Having users of your program create new classes seems like a suboptimal design choice.

Comment: Thanx ! i forgot about it "exec()".

Comment: i do know that it isn't the best way to do it, but its the only way i currently know .  Pls share what are the other ways of doing it .

Comment: does the above given method work in Python 2.5 also ?

Comment: @thecreator232 I believe that the functionality of `exec` is essentially unchanged from Python 2.4 forward (so I think it's the same in Python 2.5), but I don't have an install of Python 2.5 available to test this.

Comment: @thecreator232 Please edit that into your question so that it can be properly formatted as code.